# Completely kill ViewController programmatically In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller, kill

When i send a notification with NotificationCenter, previously opened ViewController (with diffrent data) responding my notification. For example

A to B with x data
A to B with y data
A to B with z data

After this scenario (in B viewcontroller), When i pushed a notification, notification observer calling 3 times.

I use Storyboard and programmatically navigation controller.

Comment: still you face this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In ViewWillDisapper:(Of Class A) removeObserver for notification. And in ViewWillAppear(of class A) addObserver for Notification.
Follow the same for Class B also.

Comment: I tried but it does not work. B viewcontroller has a ContainerView. It is a pageviewcontroller. Is that problem?

Comment: No, I think I wont be a problem.May I know where you are adding and removing notification observers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove notification observer in your `Bviewcontroller` add bellow method in `Bviewcontroller`

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```